# Cisco ASA bonding/teaming/port-channel capabilities

Tags: cisco, bonding, cisco-asa

This seemed to me like a really simple question that I would be able to answer by myself but I have not been able to find any info on this subject.

I have a Cisco ASA 5510 which has 4 FastEthernet interfaces. I was wondering if it would be possible to use 2 or 3 of these interfaces as a port-channel in order to agregate bandwidth for multiple VLANs.

I have found no info on the Cisco website nor on Google. Is this just a stupid/crazy idea or am I missing something ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Antoine

Edit : I checked the [Cisco ASA command reference guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa83/command/reference/p.html) and there is no port-channel command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the 5510 but from a spot of searching around I'd say it doesn't support port channels - which is surprising to be honest.

Comment: Oh good I am not crazy... Doesn't make much sense why such things wouldn't work...

Comment: it does seem bad that they didn't include it - guess they want to 'up-sell' you to a 5580 :)

Comment: Haha, indeed or a 6500 with the FWSM =P

Comment: that's what we use actually - damn Cisco :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make two of those ports into proper GigE if you buy the Security Plus license ($800):

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/prod_models_comparison.html

Keep in mind that 5510 can only do 300Mbps of filtering and 170Mbps of VPN.

Comment: Very good point ! I'll check to see what licence is installed. The licences are educationnal so I have no idea what they are really.