# How do you configuring vlans/trunk on a Cicso ASA 5510

Tags: cisco-asa, vlan, trunk

I have a Cicso ASA 5510 that I want to connect to 2 Dell PowerConnect 5500 linked in a Switch Stack.  I want to connect a trunking line to each switch so if one switch dies the other works.  The problem is I can't seem to do anything thing with vlans on the 5510 using the "Cisco ASDM 6.4 for ASA" .  Do I need to use CLI for this, or is it just not possible?
I'm new at networking so any advice would be helpful.

[Edit] I got it...
Configuration -> Interfaces -> Add (You can then setup a new interface with a vlan)  The UI was just not what I was expected it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine what you're hoping to do is to use two physical interfaces on the 5510, with each interface connected to one of the switches, and then both interfaces are joined together in software to act as a single logical interface. Cisco refers to this as EtherChannel; on servers it's often called bonding. Unfortunately, according to https://serverfault.com/a/121968/33745, the 5510 doesn't seem to support it.

What might be useful to provide some redundancy are [Redundant Interfaces](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/configuration/guide/intrface.html#wp1045838), where you can configure two interfaces together, and use them in an active/standby fashion. [This guy](http://yurisk.info/2010/08/23/redundant-interfaces-in-cisco-asa/) here describes the set up in a bit more detail. The downside of this is that all traffic will go via one connection, while the other connection will be unused until the active one fails.

**EDIT:** See @Weaver's comment below - EtherChannel is now supported as of 8.4.

Comment: As of ASA 8.4 EtherChannel is supported on ASA.  LACP is the only protocol supported other than static. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/interface_start.html#wp1329030

Comment: You're spot on - that page suggests 52 interfaces of all types (including EtherChannel) with the basic licence. The more you know, eh!

Comment: Well that's nice to know about the EtherChannel, but what about the vlans/trunk?  What to I need to do to get that working?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/interface_start.html#wp1082576. I'm not familiar with Dell switches so I can't help on that side, but it should be pretty straightforward on the ASA side.